# Jest vscode-jest Extension Running All Tests (Despite Proper Configuration and Using Git)

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jestjs, vscode-jest

As the title says, I'm using Git as source control for my project, and I'm using the below configuration:

```json
  "jest.autoRun": "watch",
  "jest.debugCodeLens.showWhenTestStateIn": ["pass", "skip", "fail", "unknown"],
  "jest.coverageFormatter": "DefaultFormatter",
  "jest.coverageColors": {
    "covered": "rgba(9, 156, 65, 0.9)",
    "uncovered": "rgba(121, 31, 10, 0.3)",
    "partially-covered": "rgba(235, 198, 52, 0.1)"
```

but no matter what, any change in any file triggers *all* tests to run, not just the affected tests.  I've also tried `"jest.autoRun": "on-save"` and it also triggers *all* tests to run, not just the ones for the saved file, whether I've got code-coverage enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify/play the single parameters. This should be the configuration you are searching for. But it is the equivalent of "on-save", so it might not work.

```
"jest.autoRun": {
   "watch": false,
   "onSave": "test-src-file",
}
```

For further information check: https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest#autorun